# For Loop to read a file line by line

Tags: bash, zsh

```
for word in $(cat link_name.list); do 
    echo "$word"; 
done
```

The for loop does not read contents line by line but as a single line. Not sure why a while loop is preferred to do this?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and https://shellcheck.net  and it is not just a while loop, you need the `read` builtin for that, Other scripting language like say, `python` does that but not the shell, also you might need to check if that `link_name.list` has carriage returns which is normal for files created in  Windows.

Comment: Thank you Jetchisel...